# What class is "EXIT_FAILURE"?

Tags: c++

In the main function, I had a lot of error testing code to make sure I successfully located and opened some files. So since I did that a lot, I made it a separate, void, function. When I previously had "return EXIT_FAILURE" in the main function it would work just like I wanted it to. But when I put it in a secondary function I named errorTest, it gets on me about returning something after declaring it a void function. So, what class is "EXIT_FAILURE", so I can differently declare that void function into returning whatever class "EXIT_FAILURE" is?

(and yes, I included the library cstdlib)

Comment: EXIT_FAILURE is an `int`.

Comment: Consider having your function throw an exception instead of using a return value, to indicate exceptional conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's an integer. Declare your function as int.

Answer (score 6):

It's a preprocessor macro defined by `#include <cstdlib>`.

It expands to an integral constant expression. This is not necessarily of type `int`, however it must have a value within the valid range of `int` so that it can be passed to `exit()`.

Answer (score 2):

EXIT_FAILURE is an `int` declared in `stdlib.h` (or `cstdlib`), so it's a primitive type, not a class.

Comment: This is C++.  It's in `cstdlib`.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. However, g++, which I'm using, accepts `stdio.h`, and I think most other compilers do as well. (Sorry, but I do more in C than C++).

Comment: Yes, most C++ compilers will include C headers.  Prior to ISO C++98, it /was/ stdlib.h in C++ as well, so some compilers may have a pre-ISO C++ version of stdlib.h as well.  But it's not a good habit for people learning the language to use the old include files, because they *are* different.

Answer (score 2):

`EXIT_SUCCESS`  and `EXIT_FAILURE` are macros defined in `stdlib.h` or `cstdlib`.